# Setting attributes using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, attributes

I have:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
console.log(items[0], items[1], items[2]);
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Players</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Alice</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>Cesar</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Producing:

```
Players
    1.Alice
    2.Bob
    3.Cesar
```

Now I want convert the integers to Roman numerals, using javascript, externally in my javascript file, **instead** of setting the numerals in the HTML-file, like this:

```
<ol type="i">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

This is my Javascript code so far, but I want to to convert the numbers to numerals:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
console.log(items[0], items[1], items[2]);
```

Comment: What you're logging are *elements*, which don't have the leading numbers in their text

Comment: if you just want to add `type="i"` the code is : `document.querySelector('#players ol').setAttribute('type', 'i')`

Comment: I don't know why you need to use JS for this. I recommend just setting `list-style-type` to `upper-roman` in CSS.

Comment: You're right. How do I set the a specific list element, ie the third one to be displayed in a specific color?(Using the style property to set the css  property `color` to set it's value so it turns red?(c#00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust your list with the `type` attribute;

```js
document.querySelector("ol").type = "I";
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
console.log(items[0], items[1], items[2]);
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Players</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Alice</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>Cesar</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just querySelect the parent 'ol' and then change it's list style in Javascript using element.style.listStyleType = "upper-roman". This should apply the style its child elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can change type attribute of the ol tag [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_type.asp)

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
document.querySelector("ol").type = "i";
console.log(items[0], items[1], items[2]);
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Players</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Alice</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>Cesar</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```